# Why are my API requests getting cancelled in javascript ( Chrome Extension )

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension
I want the function to be called on the click of a button.
I did it as below, if I give it as '**createurl()**' for onclick function, it executes the API call even if the button isn't clicked.
If the function is given as just '**createurl**' then the API request is being shown as 'cancelled' by chrome.
So how do I overcome this error ?

[Given that the API is working fine and is accepting all requests]

popup.html

```
~~other neccesary things and~~

<form>
   <button class="scrollto">Shorten It</button>
</form>
```

popup.js

```
document.querySelector(".scrollto").onclick = createurl
function createurl(){
    var data = new FormData();
    var form = document.querySelector("form");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    }
    });
    xhr.open("POST", "https://mydomain/api.php");
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

manifest.json

```
~~other neccesary things and~~

"permissions": [
    "*://*/*",
    "webNavigation",
    "cookies",
    "https://mydomain/",
    "activeTab"
  ]
```

Comment: Because a form submit causes a page transfer, which will cancel any on going ajax requests.

Comment: @Taplar if its button.onclick = **createurl()** , API call works, but it gets executed before the button is clicked. To overcome that issue I modified it to button.onclick = **createurl** So now the function is called upon button click. But API call is cancelled by chrome in this function call.

Comment: Read the answer below.  It repeats what I said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<button>`'s default behavior is to do a submit, which causes the browser to navigate away from the page (possibly back to the same page).

If you want it to just act as a place for an event handler, you need to use `type="button"`:

```
<form>
   <button class="scrollto" type="button">Shorten It</button>
</form>
```